# $ _SESSION and more users - PHP

Tags: php

A very trivial question, but it is a thought that came to me and I don't know if it can be pertinent or not, if for example in the login page, or any other page, we initialize the `$_SESSION ['name_session'];` and in the logout phase we are going to destroy them, what happens if several users simultaneously use a web portal.

I explain better that we have two users:
user1: enter the portal and the `$_SESSION` begins

Meanwhile

User2: he also connects

if user1 closes the `$_SESSION`, could it happen that even user2 will log out?

If, yes, you start the `$_SESSION`, with the user id it might be a good thing, so would the `$_SESSION`s all have unique keys?

Comment: When you create a session you also create a unique identifier. This ID is sent in a cookie to the browser. Whoever holds this cookie owns the session. When the session is destroyed the file will be deleted and the browser will be told to expire the cookie.

Comment: @Dharman perfect, so the fact of creating a session based on the user's id can also be avoided, for all the procedure that you have kindly explained to me, is it correct?

Comment: What user ID? If you have some other User ID it is not the ID of the session. Session will have its own ID. Open developer tools and check the contents of your cookies. You will notice that there is one with just bunch of letters and numbers.

Comment: Also, if a user logs in once on IE and once on Chrome there will be 2 different sessions as there are 2 different cookies, 1 in each browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP sessions are connected to a specific browser session. Each client user gets their own session, and changes made to one session have no effect on other clients.

This is done using a cookie that's sent to the browser. When you start a session, it creates a random session ID, and this is set as the `PHPSESSID` cookie. When the browser sends back this cookie, it allows PHP to find the corresponding session data.

Answer (score 1):

The session is not shared. Each user (browser / client) has it's own session. A cookie is used to track the individual sessions, as Dharman said. Anything you store in $_SESSION is stored for that individual user and is retrieved again using the session id from the cookie in the next request of that client.

Answer (score -2):

By default, it is saved in session cache (OPcache) and it is not necessary to add the user's id, php takes care of that.